# How to get Python division by -0.0 and 0.0 to result in -Inf and Inf, respectively?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ieee-754, divide-by-zero

I have a situation where it is reasonable to have a division by 0.0 or by -0.0 where I would expect to see +Inf and -Inf, respectively, as results.  It seems that Python enjoys throwing a

```
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

in either case.  Obviously, I figured that I could simply wrap this with a test for 0.0.  However, I can't find a way to distinguish between +0.0 and -0.0.  (FYI you can easily get a -0.0 by typing it or via common calculations such as -1.0 * 0.0).

IEEE handles this all very nicely, but Python seems to take pains to hide the well thought out IEEE behavior.  In fact, the fact that 0.0 == -0.0 is actually an IEEE feature so Python's behavior seriously breaks things.  It works perfectly well in C, Java, Tcl, and even JavaScript.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
from math import copysign

def divide(numerator, denominator):
    if denominator == 0.0:
        return copysign(float('inf'), denominator)
    return numerator / denominator

>>> divide(1, -0.0)
-inf
>>> divide(1, 0)
inf
```

Comment: Very nice - wouldn't have thought of doing it that way ;) +1

Comment: This is only correct for positive numerators. **Edit:** Okay, so technically, it does answer the question _as written_ ("to produce -Inf and Inf _respectively_"), so perhaps I rather take issue to the question

Comment: The sign of the resulting `inf` should depend on both the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 8):

I completely agree with @Mark Ransom, except that I would use `try` instead:

```
def f(a, b):
    try:
        return a / b
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return copysign(float('inf'), denominator)
```

The reason I recommend this is that if you are performing this function many times, you don't have to waste time each iteration checking if the value is zero before you attempt the division.

**EDIT**:

I have compared the speed of the `try` compared to the `if` function:

```
def g(a, b):
    if b == 0:
        return copysign(float('inf'), b)
    else:
        return a / b
```

Here is the tests:

```
s = time.time()
[f(10, x) for x in xrange(-1000000, 1000000, 1)]
print 'try:', time.time()-s
s = time.time()
[g(10, x) for x in xrange(-1000000, 1000000, 1)]
print 'if:', time.time()-s
```

Here is the result:

```
try: 0.573683023453
if: 0.610251903534
```

This indicates the `try` method is faster, at least on my machine.

Comment: The `try...except` is actually slower than the `if`.

Comment: @Blender  I just did some tests that disagree with that; do you have tests that show otherwise?

Comment: I can't paste it in here because it'd take up like 30 lines, but [here's a screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/sqgbwJF.png).

Comment: The difference is negligible (but consistently in favor of the `if`) for nonzero inputs, but the `if` is about twice as fast when `b` is zero.

Comment: @Blender, the `else` is redundant, I wonder if removing it would speed it up more?

Comment: @MarkRansom: It doesn't make a noticeable difference for me, but the `else` adds in an extra `LOAD_CONST`, which does take up time.

Comment: Same issue as with MarkRansom's answer: The sign of the resulting `inf` should depend on both the numerator and the denominator.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution that handles all the edge cases correctly, at least as far as I'm aware of:

```
def divide(a: float, b: float) -> float:
    try:
        return a/b
    except:
        return a*math.copysign(math.inf, b)

assert divide( 1,  1) ==  1
assert divide( 1, -1) == -1
assert divide(-1,  1) == -1
assert divide(-1, -1) ==  1
assert divide( 1,  0.0) >  1e300
assert divide( 1, -0.0) < -1e300
assert divide(-1,  0.0) < -1e300
assert divide(-1, -0.0) >  1e300
assert math.isnan(divide( 0.0,  0.0))
assert math.isnan(divide( 0.0, -0.0))
assert math.isnan(divide(-0.0,  0.0))
assert math.isnan(divide(-0.0, -0.0))
```

In the case that `b` is a zero, it basically splits the division `a/b` into `a * (1/b)` and implements `1/b` via `copysign()`. The multiplication does not throw when its arguments are `0*inf`, instead it correctly yields a NAN.

Answer (score 2):

The [gmpy2](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/) library provides an arbitrary precision floating type and also allows you to control IEEE-754 exception behavior.

```
>>> import gmpy2
>>> from gmpy2 import mpfr
>>> mpfr(1)/mpfr(0)
mpfr('inf')
>>> mpfr(1)/mpfr(-0)
mpfr('inf')
>>> mpfr(1)/mpfr("-0")
mpfr('-inf')
>>> gmpy2.get_context().trap_divzero=True
>>> mpfr(1)/mpfr(0)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
gmpy2.DivisionByZeroError: 'mpfr' division by zero in division
```

Disclaimer: I maintain gmpy2.

Comment: Thanks.  I will check out gmpy2 for another project that will benefit from arbitrary precision.  My current project needs top performance (inner loop stuff) and doesn't require arbitrary precision.