# Python: When would 0.0/0.0 =NaN or inf , when would it gives exception?

Tags: python, exception, pandas, division

I got a dataframe in python.pandas:

```
q   v         k
0   0   
16  42 
14  59 
... ...
```

Now I want let k=q/v if v!=0 else k=0.
This is how I did:

```
>>>df['k'] = df['q'].astype(float16) /df['v'].astype(float16)
q  v    k
0  0  NaN
>>>df['k'][df['v']==0] = 0.0
```

When set float16, it gives NaN. However

```
>>>0/np.float64(0) 
nan
>>>df['k'] = df['q'] /df['v'].astype(float16)
ZeroDivisionError
```

Moreover,

```
>>> df['k'] = df['q'].astype(int16)/df['v'].astype(int16)
q  v    k
0  0  inf
>>> np.int64(0)/np.int64(0)
nan
```

Why?

Answer (score 2):

you can use this for a one liner:

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'q':[0,16,14],'v':[0,42,59]})
df.astype('float64')
df['k']=(df.q/df.v).replace({ np.inf : 0 })
```

Numpy is handling the divide by zero error. (The behavior can be changed using sterr http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.seterr.html#numpy.seterr)

Here is a post that show a function on handling it in pure python:
[How to get Python division by -0.0 and 0.0 to result in -Inf and Inf, respectively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16226633/how-to-get-python-division-by-0-0-and-0-0-to-result-in-inf-and-inf-respective)

Comment: Thank you a lot! I read the seterr doc. and the other stackoverflow you gave. I refined the question. I am wondering why setting them inf16, float16, or set the whole dataframe gives different result: inf, NaN,inf, respectively.